# Performance bottleneck while importing a Excel file via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I received a task to import an Excel file (xlsx), which is created by a third party (we do not have influence on structure, names and content) into a database. This file includes several sheets with non-standard sheet names (instead of "Sheet1" or "Data" or something it features names like "1 2 Data of grp 1 & 2 incl. test" - dummy name only for structure description). I have to import one specific sheet from this file which features round about 4000 lines with 205 columns. The file has a size of round about 20 MB. Of these 205 columns, only 65 columns (not sequentially in the sheet) have to be imported (something like col 1-4, 10-16, 50-100, ...).

I tried to implement this import via OleDB connection, but I receive an error, that the sheet name is invalid (I guess it is connected to the & and . and maybe spaces in the name...).

Now I implemented the import via `Excel.Workbook` and `Excel.Range` and fetch the corresponding cell via `xlRange.Cells[i, colId].Value2.ToString()`. First of all I loop through all columns of the first row in the range in order to get the names of the columns. While doing so I check if the column is included in the list of the 65 required columns and if this is the case, I add the column ID and name to a datatable. In the next step I loop through all rows in the sheet and for each sheet I loop through my datatable in order to fetch the data of the cell in columns identified as required.

Seemingly, this wasn't a good idea: I cancelled the process (Just looping through rows and columns; no data processing / inserting or whatever at that point of time) after 25 minutes. Furthermore I noticed, that the memory used by Excel hat reached more than 200 MB before I cancelled the process.

Is there a more performant way to get only data from the columns required?

From a database point of view, 4000 rows isn't that abig amount, but I guess the 205 columns might cause the problem, resulting in a total of 820k cells... seemingly the idea of filtering via data table didn't have the expected effect of reducing the workload.

Comment: Are these all inserts? Off the top of my head you could 1) possibly change the name of the sheet and then do the import via OleDB 2) read the entire sheet into a two dimensional array and loop through that 3) If they are all inserts use bulk insert or copy

Comment: @Kevin no inserts so far - for the time being only looping in order to get all rows and all required columns. But yes, in the future all records will have to be inserted into the DB. As mentioned only 65 of the 205 columns are relevant. So loading the whole 4000x205 array could work? Never loaded an Excel file of this size completely to memory (and got no idea how to implement it without looping over column and row index).

Comment: @Kevin renaming is not an option - the file will be pushed to a directory and a process should import it automatically

Comment: Not an expert myself on the topic (exactly the opposite), but have you considered the Open XML SDK? See this, it may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet

Comment: Personally I would try bulk loading the entire sheet, then strip out anything I don't want. It's usually much quicker to do this in SQL than in Excel. If the format isn't ever going to change then this becomes a simple EXCEL -> dump table -> clean table operation. If you can automate saving the single sheet you actually want as a CSV then even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of trial and error, I finally managed to get the OleDB query running on the Excel sheet. As I read in another thread (guess even another website), the OleDB query will not work if the sheet name (or column names) include dots. These will have - during the query, not in the file itself - to be replaces by a `#`, so the query of a sheet name `value a & b incl. test` will look something like this: `SELECT [col1], col[2]... FROM [value a & b incl# test$]`.